# gpu found. vendor id 10de device if 0x174d checking for bad AMD Vulkan driver version

Tags: android-studio, gpu, emulation, nvidia, vulkan

Android Emulator gives this error: Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554.
The problem could be using a video as background because if i don't use it, the emulator runs correctly. The strange thing is that the same project has no problems on my friends' computers. Maybe the problem is the GPU? (nvidia geforce mx130) It seems it's trying to look for an AMD gpu even if i don't have it...
Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:
gpu found. vendor id 8086 device id 0x174d
checking for bad AMD vulkan driver version...
amdvlk64.dll not found. Checking for amdvlk32...
amdvlk32.dll not found. No bad AMD Vulkan driver versions found.
checking for bad vulkan-1.dll version...
vulkan-1.dll version: 1.1.114.0
Not known bad vulkan-1.dll version; continue.

Comment: 8086 is Intel. This is some kind of notebook with switchable graphics, which is always fickle. The log seems fine; it just seems to look for blacklisted drivers. Anyway, try to update both Intel's and NVidia's driver. Or you could try to change\disable the emulator HW acceleration settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried but i had no luck